# Stored procedure too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the stored procedure shown below, which reads data from a table that contains two columns: the first column `row_id` which contains the id of the row and the second column `row_data` which contains a JSON that contains the data then it convert that JSON to columns and insert it to a new table.

The stored procedure reads from one table that contains JSON and normalize that JSON to a new table with deleting the duplicated rows:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.basic_json_normalization_incr
    @tableNamep NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @rows_count INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @raw_tableName NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @chargement NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @truncateQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @columns_list NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @json_query_part NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @json_query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    DECLARE @separator NVARCHAR(2) = '';
    DECLARE @sqldelete NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @sqlinsert NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @raw_tableName = 'dbo.raw' + @tableNamep;

    SELECT @columns_list = COALESCE(@columns_list + ', ' + '[' + column_name + ']', '[' + column_name + ']')
    FROM dbo.schemaSource
    WHERE _enabled = 1 AND table_name = @tableNamep;

    DECLARE json_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT CASE
                   WHEN single_mult = 'M'
                       THEN CONCAT('[', column_name, '] NVARCHAR(MAX) ', 'AS JSON')
                   ELSE CONCAT('[', column_name, '] NVARCHAR(MAX) ', '''' + '$.', column_name, '''')
               END
        FROM dbo.schemaSource WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE _enabled = 1
          AND table_name = @tableNamep;

    OPEN json_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM json_cursor INTO @json_query_part;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @json_query = @json_query + @separator + @json_query_part;
        SET @separator = ',';
        
        FETCH NEXT FROM json_cursor INTO @json_query_part;
    END;

    CLOSE json_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE json_cursor;

    -- Determine the duplicate check column based on table name
    DECLARE @duplicateCheckColumn NVARCHAR(MAX);
    
    SET @duplicateCheckColumn = '_id';
    
    -- Build the dynamic SQL query for insertion with duplicate and CURR_NO check

    SET @sqldelete = N'DELETE FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE _id COLLATE French_CI_AS IN (SELECT raw_id COLLATE French_CI_AS FROM raw' + @tableNamep + ');';
        
    SET @sqlinsert =  N'
    INSERT INTO dbo.' + @tableName + '(_id, ORIGINAL_ID, ' + @columns_list + ')
    SELECT j.[_id], j.[ORIGINAL_ID], ' + @columns_list + '
    FROM ' + @raw_tableName + ' r
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.raw_data) WITH (
        _id nvarchar(155) '$._id' STRICT,
        ORIGINAL_ID nvarchar(150) '$.ORIGINAL_ID',
        ' + @json_query + '
    ) AS j
';
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqldelete;
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlinsert;

        SELECT @rows_count = @@ROWCOUNT;
        COMMIT;
        END;
END;
GO
```

The problem is that I'm dealing with tables with a large amount of data, so this stored procedure is very slow.
here is a sample data for the Table `ACCOUNT`:

table `rawACCOUNT`:

```
|raw_id|raw_data
|001   |{"_id":"001","ORIGINAL_ID":"001","CATEGORY":"65","ACCOUNT_OFFICER":"1","OPENING_DATE":"20100322","CURR_NO":"3","DATE_TIME":"2112091237","DEPT_CODE":"13"}|
```

expected table `ACCOUNT`:

```
|ORIGINAL_ID|_id|INSERT_DATE   |ACCOUNT_OFFICER|CATEGORY|CURR_NO|CUSTOMER|DATE_LAST_UPDATE|DATE_TIME |DEPT_CODE|OPENING_DATE|INACTIV_MARKER|
|001        |001|20230906085135|1              |65      |3      |NULL    |NULL            |2112091237|13       |20100322    |NULL          |
```

Is there any optimizations that I apply to make it run faster?

> PS: I used to use STRING_AGG instead of CURSOR but it showed me this
> error:

```
The result of STRING_AGG aggregation has exceeded the 8,000-byte limit. Use LOB types to avoid truncation of the result.
```

Comment: Cursors are slow, so remove the cursor. Otherwise you need to profile the SP and work out which parts are slow. Then inspect the execution plan for the slow parts to investigate why it's slow. Without access to that information we cannot assist

Comment: You'll likely be better off here taking a step back and explaining the problem, not the (slow) solution. Provide sample data and expected results in a *consumable* format.

Comment: the collate stuff in the delete is probably the issue, i don't know how large your json data is, but you'd do well to try to make the delete indexed by removing collates and create proper indexes

Comment: @ThomA i've provided a sample data. My code is working very well but it is very slow and i'm trating large table for example for the table 'ACCOUNT' the number of rows = 800k (and the table Account is the smallest table)

Comment: That's just a single row; it doesn't really explain why you're using a `CURSOR` so I don't think it really explains the problem you're trying to solve. Are you "normalising" your JSON RBAR (**r**ow **b**y **a**gonising **r**ow)? `OPENJSON` can cater for *many* rows. If you are really dealing with a *single* JSON value, then that `CURSOR` and dynamic SQL literally have no need being there.

Comment: @ThomA Don't think cursor is the issue, it just builds the necessary openjson-string to handle their columns (i guess :D), it seems to be some sort of dynamic json mapping depending on target table metadata

Comment: @ThomA i'm using CURSOR instead of STRING_AGG to concatenate the json_query because sometimes the STRING_AGG is too small (in size) to handel the json_query

Comment: @Stu yes it is working and levring the requested result but it is very slow

Comment: `STRING_AGG` can handle up to 2billion bytes worth of data though, if you are getting truncation with `STRING_AGG` then you would with a cursor, and you are stating you have a string that is *over* **2GB** in size.

Comment: @ThomA here is the error of STRING_AGG: The result of STRING_AGG aggregation has exceeded the 8,000-byte limit. Use LOB types to avoid truncation of the result.

Comment: *"Use LOB types to avoid truncation of the result."* So why aren't you using a LOB (`MAX` length) type? The error is telling you both the problem *and* the solution.

Comment: i tried to but it have some other effects on the procedure so i decided to use the cursor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a cursor here. Just use `STRING_AGG`.

You probably also want an index on the `_id` column.

Furthermore:

- Object name variables should be `sysname`.
- Use `QUOTENAME` for correct quoting.
- You don't need to specify the JSON property name if it's the same as the column name.
- Set the columns to the correct collation in the first place, otherwise it will need to do a full scan as it cannot use indexes if you change the collation inside the query.
- Don't use variable coalescing for aggregating strings, it's unreliable. Use `STRING_AGG` instead.
- Don't use `NOLOCK` it has serious data integrity implications and is not a go-faster switch.
- You need to get the rowcount from within the dynamic SQL, using an output parameter.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.basic_json_normalization_incr
    @tableNamep sysname,
    @tableName sysname,
    @rows_count INT OUTPUT
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE @raw_tableName NVARCHAR(1000) = 'dbo.' + QUOTENAME('raw' + @tableNamep);
DECLARE @main_tableName NVARCHAR(1000) = 'dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName);
DECLARE @columns_list NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @json_query NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @raw_tableName

SELECT @columns_list =
  STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME(column_name) AS nvarchar(max)), ', ')
FROM dbo.schemaSource
WHERE _enabled = 1
  AND table_name = @tableNamep;

SELECT @json_query =
  STRING_AGG(
    CAST(
      QUOTENAME(column_name)
        + ' nvarchar(max)'
        + CASE WHEN single_mult = 'M' THEN ' AS JSON' END
      AS nvarchar(max)),
    ','
  )
FROM dbo.schemaSource
WHERE _enabled = 1
  AND table_name = @tableNamep;

SET @sql = N'
BEGIN TRAN;

DELETE FROM dbo.' + @main_tableName + '
WHERE _id IN (
    SELECT raw_id
    FROM ' + raw_tableName + '
);

INSERT INTO dbo.' + @main_tableName + '
  (_id, ORIGINAL_ID, ' + @columns_list + ')
SELECT j.[_id], j.[ORIGINAL_ID], ' + @columns_list + '
FROM ' + @raw_tableName + ' r
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.raw_data)
  WITH (
    _id nvarchar(155) '$._id' STRICT,
    ORIGINAL_ID nvarchar(150),
    ' + @json_query + '
  ) AS j;

SET @rows_count = @@ROWCOUNT;

COMMIT;
';

PRINT @sql;  -- Your friend

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@rows_count int OUTPUT',
  @rows_count = @rows_count OUTPUT;
```

Comment: No actually, i used to use the STRING_AGG but it showed me this error for some tables:
The result of STRING_AGG aggregation has exceeded the 8,000-byte limit. Use LOB types to avoid truncation of the result.

Comment: You need to cast to `nvarchar(max)` see edit. You must have a pretty wide table if you managed to get such a large aggregation.

Comment: no it does not work, i need to convert it to LOB which have other effects on the procedure

Comment: The conversion is on the `STRING_AGG` as part of the dynamic query building phase. It has no relation to the actual query being run in `sp_executesql`. Look at the code carefully.